# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FirstApp.Model.TeamDetails>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am getting this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<FirstApp.Model.TeamDetails>`

What's wrong with my code?

Here is my code

`TeamDetails` Class

```
public class TeamDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? UserCount { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewTeamList
{
    public List<TeamDetails> TeamNext { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Next(int dataid)
{
    ViewTeamList viewTeamList = new ViewTeamList();
    var a = from t in tDbContext.Teams
            join u in tDbContext.Users on t.TeamId equals u.TeamId into g
            where t.Deleted != true
            select new { TeamId= t.TeamId,TeamName = t.TeamName, Description = t.Description, UserId = g.Count() };

    var next = a.OrderBy(t1 => t1.TeamId).Where(t1 => t1.TeamId > dataid).FirstOrDefault();
    viewTeamList.TeamNext = a.ToList(); 
    return PartialView("_ViewTeamDetails", viewTeamList);
}
```

I'm not able to assign this value to

```
viewTeamList.TeamNext = a....;
```

Comment: You've constructed an anonymous type in there: `select new { TeamId = ...`, this is not compatible with `TeamDetails`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This constructs an anonymous type instead of `TeamDetails`

```
select new { TeamId= t.TeamId,TeamName = t.TeamName, Description = t.Description, UserId = g.Count() }
```

You should change it to below

```
select new TeamDetails { TeamId = t.TeamId, TeamName = t.TeamName, Description = t.Description, UserCount = g.Count() }
```

so `a.ToList()` would be a `List<FirstApp.Model.TeamDetails>`